After upgrading to spring-boot 3.2 I get LazyInitializationException
My project was using spring boot 3.1.12, and I upgraded version to 3.2.0, but I started getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session when trying to access child entities of my parent entity.
spring-boot-starter-jpa:3.2.0 uses Hibernate 6.3, in migration guide there is a paragraph 'Batch Fetching and LockMode', maybe this new behavor is the cause of my problem.
@EntityGraph is not an option because it increases endpoint response time too much, the same goes for fetch join query (Hibernate will make 2 fetch joins in query for each parent entity, of which there may be many)
How can I fix this problem, if I use Spring Data JPA? My method is annotated with @Transactional and it worked fine before. I get exception at childItems = it.transfers.toDto() line
Pseudocode:
@Transactional
override suspend fun report(...) {
   val items = loadItems(...)

   toItemsReport(items, ...)
}

private suspend fun loadItems(...) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { {
   val criteria: Specification<ItemEntity> = ...
   val items = itemRepository.findAll(criteria, page)
   items
}

private suspend fun toItemsReport(items, ...) {
   return ItemExport(
        slice = items,
        reports = items.map {
            ItemExport(
                item = it.toDto,
                childItems = it.transfers.toDto()
            )
         }
   )
}

Item repository:
interface ItemRepository: JpaRepository<ItemEntity, Int>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ItemEntity> {
         override fun findAll(spec: Specification<ItemEntity>, pageable: Pageable): Page<ItemEntity>
}


Which method throws exception? Which method annotated with @Transactional?

Added some pseudo code

Didn't notice it is kotlin question. @Transactional don't work with coroutines.

Some details here

omg, I removed 'suspend' keyword from methods and it started working properly, but much slower...anyway, thank you very much
